# What is the algorithm behind search functionality in VI editor

Tags: linux, vi

Even when i open a new file, the search command works really fast even on a very big file?
what is the algorithm used to implement it.

I am just curious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just your regular regex implementation.

First, the pattern is compiled into a regular expression (`vim_regcomp`).

Next, `vim_regexec{_multi,_nl,_both}` is used to execute it. It does so by processing the various atoms step by step (there's a an explicit backtracking stack).

Now, the leaf nodes of the regex are just handled by pedestrian functions like

- `vim_strbyte`
- `vim_strchr`
- `cstrchr`; This, as an example, shows how "straightforward" the implementation is (especially, if you look at the simpler case when `FEAT_MBYTE` is not defined)

  ```
  /*
  * cstrchr: This function is used a lot for simple searches, keep it fast!
  */
      static char_u *
  cstrchr(s, c)
      char_u  *s;
      int     c;
  {
      char_u  *p;
      int     cc;

      if (!ireg_ic
  #ifdef FEAT_MBYTE
              || (!enc_utf8 && mb_char2len(c) > 1)
  #endif
              )
          return vim_strchr(s, c);

      /* tolower() and toupper() can be slow, comparing twice should be a lot
      * faster (esp. when using MS Visual C++!).
      * For UTF-8 need to use folded case. */
  #ifdef FEAT_MBYTE
      if (enc_utf8 && c > 0x80)
          cc = utf_fold(c);
      else
  #endif
          if (MB_ISUPPER(c))
          cc = MB_TOLOWER(c);
      else if (MB_ISLOWER(c))
          cc = MB_TOUPPER(c);
      else
          return vim_strchr(s, c);

  #ifdef FEAT_MBYTE
      if (has_mbyte)
      {
          for (p = s; *p != NUL; p += (*mb_ptr2len)(p))
          {
              if (enc_utf8 && c > 0x80)
              {
                  if (utf_fold(utf_ptr2char(p)) == cc)
                      return p;
              }
              else if (*p == c || *p == cc)
                  return p;
          }
      }
      else
  #endif
          /* Faster version for when there are no multi-byte characters. */
          for (p = s; *p != NUL; ++p)
              if (*p == c || *p == cc)
                  return p;

      return NULL;
  }
  ```

Now short story is:

- the regex implementation is involved (because it supports a lot of features like Unicode case folding)
- the implementation in `src/regexp.c` runs for 5966 LoC (7652 including comments and whitespace)

however, if you were looking for 'sophisticated' algorithms (like e.g. Boyer Moore) you're not gonna find it, because, frankly, finding text in a single file just doesn't require it.

Now, if you want to look at top-performance search algorithms, you might want to look at GNU `grep`'s sources instead ... :)

---

All counts based on `vim-7.3.547` in the debian package archives